# PreferenceFragment::onPreferenceTreeClick return value - what does it do?

Tags: android

It seems I can't find out how the return value of [PreferenceFragment::onPreferenceTreeClick(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#onPreferenceTreeClick%28android.preference.PreferenceScreen,%20android.preference.Preference%29) is interpreted. In the docs there's not mentioned how the return value is used (Eclipse says "@inheritDoc" and the [Android HTML reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#onPreferenceTreeClick%28android.preference.PreferenceScreen,%20android.preference.Preference%29) has an empty body).

I tried looking it up in the deprecated API on [PreferenceActivity::onPreferenceTreeClick(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onPreferenceTreeClick%28android.preference.PreferenceScreen,%20android.preference.Preference%29) but all it says is, well, it is deprecated.

Additionally I tried returning true and false from the method, but it seemed to me as it had no effect on anything.

So - If anyone could please be so kind to tell me what the return value changes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code that calls this is in [`Preference#performClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java) and it does the following:

```
PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
if (preferenceManager != null) {
    PreferenceManager.OnPreferenceTreeClickListener listener = preferenceManager
            .getOnPreferenceTreeClickListener();
    if (preferenceScreen != null && listener != null
            && listener.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, this)) {
        return;
    }
}

if (mIntent != null) {
    Context context = getContext();
    context.startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

returning `true` will return immediately while returning `false` will check if there is an `Intent` set for this `PreferenceScreen` and [start the specified `Activity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275015/android-start-activity-from-preferences-xml).

If you `return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference)` you will also cause the following piece of code from [`PreferenceFragment`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.java) to run

```
if (preference.getFragment() != null &&
        getActivity() instanceof OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback) {
    return ((OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback)getActivity()).onPreferenceStartFragment(
            this, preference);
}
return false;
```

This one checks if there is a [`Fragment` to be shown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:fragment). If not `Preference` will then look for an `Intent`.

#### TLDR

Preferences can start either `Intent`s or `Fragment`s. The meaning of the return value is

- `true` : nothing happens, both fragments and intents are ignored
- `false` : fragments are ignored, intents are executed
- `super.onPreference..` : tries fragment first, intent second

`return false;` or `return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(...)` should be usually the right thing to return. The meaning of the return value is roughly "Start Activity by intent if exist?". You should return `true` if you have specified an intent but don't want to start the activity. It does not matter in most other cases since you rarely handle clicks if you have that intent specified.