# OnPreferenceTreeClick deprecated

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm replacing a few deprecated methods in Xamarin.Android code which come from the **PreferenceActivity** class. I can find alternatives in the **Activity** and **PreferenceFragments** classes for most of the deprecated methods, but cannot find any documentation which suggests a suitable replacement for OnTreePreferenceClicked().

Basically, I want this method to be called when the user taps on one of my preferences. The code works fine, but I want rid of the deprecated method.

```
public override bool OnPreferenceTreeClick(
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference)
    {
        switch (preference.Key)
        {
            case PreferenceKeys.Account:
                return OnAccountClick(preference);
            case PreferenceKeys.ClearPictureCache:
                return OnClearPictureCacheClick(preference);
            case PreferenceKeys.Version:
                return OnVersionNumberClick(preference);
            default:
                return base.OnPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity#onPreferenceTreeClick(android.preference.PreferenceScreen,%20android.preference.Preference)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Preferences.PreferenceActivity.OnPreferenceTreeClick/p/Android.Preferences.PreferenceScreen/Android.Preferences.Preference/

Comment: That's the deprecated method I'm saying that I _don't_ want to use.

Comment: @uprightbassfan78 You are using the old style, that "feature" is not relevant when using an Activity that hosts a PreferenceFragment(s). Review this answer for what that code is doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18363310/4984832